# Align strings of a dataframe in columns in r

Tags: r, string, match, reshape

I have a big data frame, and I want strings to be aligned in columns based on suffixes (substrings), the source dataframe looks like this:

notst stands for other variable prefix to be ignored

```
#            col1       col2       col3 
#        notst-s1   notst-s2   notst-x3
#        notst-s1   notst-x3   notst-a5   
#        notst-s2   notst-a5
#        notst-x3   notst-a5
```

The result, should be:

```
#            col1       col2       col3       col4 
#        notst-s1   notst-s2   notst-x3
#        notst-s1              notst-x3   notst-a5   
#                   notst-s2              notst-a5
#                              notst-x3   notst-a5
```

Edit:

Consider the whole suffix (after "-"). It does not have numbers. There are cases in which the whole string ("xxxx-spst") should be matched (*) because the xxxx part of the string comes in several versions.

For:

```
df <- read.table(text="
           col1         col2        col3 
         st1-ab     stb-spst    sta-spst
       stc-spst     sta-spst      st4-ab   
       stb-spst       st7-ab
         st9-ba     stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

a possible result, could be: (column name and order is irrelevant)

```
#           col1         col2        col3       col4    
#         st1-ab     stb-spst    sta-spst      
#         st4-ab     stc-spst    sta-spst         
#         st7-ab     stb-spst       
#                    stb-spst                 st9-ba
```

(*) Note that in row 2, col2, "stc-spst" seems misplaced, but it is not a problem because the value stb-spst does not exist in that row, so for that particular case, only the suffix ("spst") matters. In other words, when the whole string (prefix-suffix) matches others (in other rows), they should be in the same column, if not, when the suffix matches the suffix (of other rows), they should be in the same column. The resulting dataframe should have the same number of rows as the original and the lowest number of columns possible.

EDIT. answer should be universal and work for:

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stc-spst     sta-spst    st4-ab     st2-ab
stb-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
st9-ba       stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

for example, also.
Possible result:

```
#           col1         col2        col3       col4    col5      col6     col7
#         st1-ab     stb-spst    sta-spst    std-spst  
#         st4-ab     stc-spst    sta-spst               st2-ab  
#         st7-ab     stb-spst                                     sa-ac  
#                    stb-spst                                           st9-ba
```

example 3

```
df3 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stb-spst     sta-ab    
sta-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
sta-spst     stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

desired output

```
  col1   col2     col3     col4     col5  
1       st1-ab    sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
2       sta-ab             stb-spst         
3 sa-ac st7-ab    sta-spst                  
4                 sta-spst stb-spst
```

EDIT example 4. In order to make the task easier, you can explicitly define in a function the suffixes that may have more than one possible prefix per row. In this example ("spst"). So any string with suffix different to "spst" should have only one possible prefix per row and can and must be collapsed into one column in the resulting df, as the col2 in the desired output. This is not what I wanted originally because I will get more columns than expected. Ideally strings containing spst and different prefixes should appear in the lowest numbers of columns possible. See (* above).

```
df4 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stb-spst     st1-ab    
sta-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
sta-spst     stb-spst    st7-ab",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

desired output

```
row_id  col1  col2          col3     col4     col5
1             st1-ab        sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
2             st1-ab                 stb-spst         
3       sa-ac st7-ab        sta-spst                  
4             st7-ab        sta-spst stb-spst
```

Comment: Can you provide us with some logic for how the data is being moved around?  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Ferroao  The edited new example data and the expected output for that one is confusing

Comment: it has preffix and suffix (separeted by -) as previously. but no numbers in suffix. Output based on suffixes, and in some cases the whole string, when more than one match (cols 2 and 3).

Comment: In example 3, i think the output on row 2, col 2  should be sta-ab (or the input on row 2, col2 should be st2-ab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with four examples, but this version was done without regard for the information you added as a workaround in example 4.

The main addition is shuffle logic (which may be quite slow) to compact the resulting dataframe form right to left. It's possible that the `assigned_by_suffix` and the `assigned_by_single_suffix` are no longer required, but I have not verified.

Outputs are at the end of the code

```
# examples
df1 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3 
st1-ab     stb-spst    sta-spst
stc-spst     sta-spst      st4-ab   
stb-spst       st7-ab
st9-ba     stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stc-spst     sta-spst    st4-ab     st2-ab
stb-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
st9-ba       stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df3 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stb-spst     sta-ab    
sta-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
sta-spst     stb-spst",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df4 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3       col4 
st1-ab       stb-spst    sta-spst   std-spst
stb-spst     st1-ab    
sta-spst     st7-ab      sa-ac
sta-spst     stb-spst    st7-ab",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(assertthat)

suffix <- function(s) {str_extract(s, "[^\\-]+$")}

# make a tall dataframe with melt, and get the suffix
dfm <- df4 %>% 
  mutate(row_id = seq_along(col1)) %>%
  melt(id.vars="row_id") %>%
  select(-2) %>%
  filter(value != "") %>%
  mutate(suffix = suffix(value)) %>%
  arrange(value)
assert_that(!any(duplicated(dfm[c("row_id", "value")])))

# initialize 
combined <- data.frame()
remaining <- dfm

# get the groups with more than 1 value
matched_values  <- dfm %>%
  group_by(value, suffix) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  filter(n>1) %>%
  rename(group_id = value) %>%
  ungroup()

# .. and assign the group ids that match
assigned_by_value <- remaining %>% 
  inner_join(matched_values %>% select(group_id), by = c("value" = "group_id")) %>%
  mutate(group_id = value) %>%
  select(row_id, value, suffix, group_id)
combined <- combined %>% bind_rows(assigned_by_value)
remaining <- dfm %>% anti_join(combined, by=c("row_id", "value"))
# find the remaining suffixes 
matched_suffixes <- remaining  %>%
  group_by(suffix) %>%
  summarize(n=n()) %>%
  filter(n>1) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  ungroup()

# ... and assign those that match
assigned_by_suffix <- remaining %>%
  inner_join(matched_suffixes, by="suffix") %>%
  mutate(group_id = suffix)
combined <- bind_rows(combined, assigned_by_suffix)
remaining <- remaining %>% anti_join(combined, by=c("row_id", "value"))


# All that remain are singles assign matches by suffix, choosing the match with fewest
assigned_by_single_suffix <- remaining %>%
  inner_join(matched_values, by = "suffix") %>%
  top_n(1, n) %>%
  head(1) %>%
  select(-n)
combined <- bind_rows(combined, assigned_by_single_suffix)
remaining <- remaining %>% anti_join(combined, by=c("row_id", "value"))

# get the remaining unmatched
unmatched <- remaining%>%
  mutate(group_id = value)
combined <- bind_rows(combined, unmatched)
remaining <- remaining %>% anti_join(combined, by=c("row_id", "value"))
assert_that(nrow(remaining) == 0)

# any overloads (duplicates) need to bump to their own column
dups <- duplicated(combined[,c("row_id", "group_id")])
combined$group_id[dups] <- combined$value[dups]

assert_that(nrow(combined) == nrow(dfm))

# spread the result

result <- spread(combined %>% select(-suffix), group_id, value, fill ="")

# Shuffle any matching suffix from right to left, so l long as there
# is corresponding space an that the whole column can move
# i is source (startign from right) - j is target (starting from right) 
#
drop_cols = c()
suffixes <- suffix(names(result))
for (i in (ncol(result)):3) {
  for(j in (i-1):2) {
    if (suffixes[i] == suffixes[j]) {
      non_empty <- which(result[,i] != "") # list of source to move
      can_fill  <- which(result[,j] == "") # list of targets can be filled
      can_move   <- all(non_empty %in% can_fill) # is to move a subset of can_fill? 

      # if there's space, shuffle the column down
      if (can_move ) {
        # shuffle down
        result[,j] <- if_else(result[,j] != "", result[,j], result[,i]) 
        drop_cols <- c(drop_cols, i)
        result[,i] <- NA
        break
      }
    }                   
  }
}

if (!is.null(drop_cols)) {
  result <- result[,-drop_cols]
}
result

# Example 1
#   row_id     ab st9-ba sta-spst stb-spst
# 1      1 st1-ab        sta-spst stb-spst
# 2      2 st4-ab        sta-spst stc-spst
# 3      3 st7-ab                 stb-spst
# 4      4        st9-ba          stb-spst

# Example 2
#  row_id     ab sa-ac     spst st2-ab st9-ba sta-spst stb-spst
# 1      1 st1-ab       std-spst               sta-spst stb-spst
# 2      2 st4-ab       stc-spst st2-ab        sta-spst         
# 3      3 st7-ab sa-ac                                 stb-spst
# 4      4                              st9-ba          stb-spst 

# Example 3
#   row_id     ab sa-ac sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
# 1      1 st1-ab       sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
# 2      2 sta-ab                stb-spst         
# 3      3 st7-ab sa-ac sta-spst                  
# 4      4              sta-spst stb-spst   

# Example 4
#   row_id sa-ac st1-ab sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
# 1      1       st1-ab sta-spst stb-spst std-spst
# 2      2       st1-ab          stb-spst         
# 3      3 sa-ac st7-ab sta-spst                  
# 4      4       st7-ab sta-spst stb-spst         
>
```

Comment: I see the issue, and have misunderstood some of the goal. i will take one last attempt

Answer (score 4):

We can do this by first `melt`ing the dataset, extract the numeric index from the elements, create a row/column index based on that and assign the elements to a `matrix` created based on the max value of the index.

```
library(reshape2)
d1 <- na.omit(transform(melt(as.matrix(df1)), v1 = as.numeric(sub("\\D+", "", value))))
m1 <- matrix("", nrow = max(d1$Var1), ncol = max(d1$v1))
m1[as.matrix(d1[c("Var1", "v1")])]  <- as.character(d1$value) 
d2 <- as.data.frame(m1[,!!colSums(m1!="")])
colnames(d2) <- paste0("col", seq_along(d2))
d2
#     col1     col2     col3     col4
#1 notst-s1 notst-s2 notst-x3         
#2 notst-s1          notst-x3 notst-a5
#3          notst-s2          notst-a5
#4                   notst-x3 notst-a5
```

Comment: This works when having numbers as in the example before the edit. However, this does not work if the strings share the number, for ex. -s1 and -x1 should also be in different columns. Broadly speaking, text without numbers (as in the edit) should also be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Matrix indexing might make this a possibility:

```
sel <- dat!=""
unq <- unique(dat[sel])
mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=nrow(dat), ncol=length(unq))

mat[cbind(row(dat)[sel],  match(dat[sel], unq) )] <- dat[sel]

#     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
#[1,] "notst-s1" "notst-s2" "notst-x3" NA        
#[2,] "notst-s1" NA         "notst-x3" "notst-a5"
#[3,] NA         "notst-s2" NA         "notst-a5"
#[4,] NA         NA         "notst-x3" "notst-a5"
```

Where `dat` was imported as:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
    col1       col2       col3 
notst-s1   notst-s2   notst-x3
notst-s1   notst-x3   notst-a5   
notst-s2   notst-a5
notst-x3   notst-a5",header=TRUE,fill=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you thelatemail, however, your answer does not consider that "notst" string may vary, the answer of akrun considers that.